# ListChanged Event not firing?

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, datagridview, bindinglist, listchanged

I have a class with a `bindinglist(of T)` in it. The `bindinglist` is bound to a `datagridview` on my form. When items are added to the `bindinglist`, they show up in the `datagridview` however the `scrollbar` never changes to accommodate for the new data. I am starting to think this is because the `Listchanged` event isn't being fired (or properly captured by my form). I have my code set up like this:

Data Class:

```
Public Class data

    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
    Public Sub new(byVal att1 as string, ByVal att2 as string)
       Attribute1 = att1
       Attribute2 = att2

    End sub

    Private mAttribute1 as string
    Public Property Attribute1 as string
        Get
            return mAttribute1
        End get
        Set(ByVal value as string)
            mAttribute1 = value
            OnPropertyChanged("Attribute1")
        End Set
    End Property
    Private mAttribute2 as string
    Public Property Attribute2 as string
        Get
            return mAttribute2
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value as string)
            mAttribute2 = value
            OnPropertyChanged("Attribute2")
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal name As String)
         RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(name))
    End Sub

    Public Sub ChangeDataFormat()
        'change from one format to the other
    End Sub
End Class
```

Data Generator Class:

```
Public Class dataGenerator()
    private myThread as New System.Theading.Thread(address of StartDataGeneration)
    Public Sub new()
        mDataList = new bindingList(of Data)
        mDataList.RaiseListChangedEvents = True
    Private WithEvents mDataList as bindingList(Of Data)
    Public readonly DataList as bindingList(of Data)
        Get
            Return mDataList
        End Get
    End property
    Private Sub StartDataGeneration()
        dim att1 as integer = 1
        dim att2 as integer = 2
        for i as Integer = 0 to 1000
            mDataList.Insert(0,New Data(att1.ToString,att2.ToString)
            att1 *= 2
            att2 *=3
        next
    End Sub
    Public Sub StartDataThread()
        myThread.Start()
    End Sub
    Public Sub ChangeDataFormat()
        for each d as data in mDataList
            d.ChangeDataFormat()
        next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Form:

```
Public class Form1
    Private myGenerators as new BindingList(of dataGenerator)
    Private myDataGrids as new BindingList(of DataGridView)
    Private Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Mybase.Load
          dim NumberOfGenerators as integer = Convert.ToInt32(My.Settings.CraneCount)
          for i as integer = 1 to NumberOfGenerators
              Dim newGenerator As New DataGenerator()
              Dim newTab as Ne tabPage(i.ToString)
              Dim NewGrid as New DataGridView
              newTab.Controls.Add(newGrid)
              newGrid.DataSource = newGenerator.DataList
              myGenerators.Add(newGrid)
          next
    End Sub
    Private Sub ButtonStart_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonStart.Click
        for each generator as dataGenerator in myGenerators
             generator.StartDataThread()
         next
    End Sub
    Private Sub ButtonChangeFormat_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonChangeFormat.Click
        for each generator as dataGenerator in myGenerators
             generator.ChangeDataFormat()
         next
   End Sub
End Class
```

I know that there is a lot of code but I wanted to be clear. So when I click the start button the new items start appearing, however, once they get to the bottom of the grid the scroll bar doesn't appear. If I click the Change Format button the data changes format and updates in the grid properly. I was under the impression that the `ListChanged` event would automatically work with a `bindinglist` and `datagridview`.  I tried calling update and refresh on `myDataGridView` and setting `datagridview.datasource` to nothing and then back to `DataList`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: @LarsTech thanks for the response. To complicate things further the datagrid is actually on a tab in a tabcontrol(there are a number of datagrids each on their own tab each running a datagenerator. The tabcontrol is indeed added to the forms control collection and I added the datagrid to the tab's controls. However it still doesn't seem to want to work.

Comment: So I simplified things a bit the program requires a variable number of tabpages/datagrids/datagenerators so they are created dynamically. If you want I can update the code with that information

Comment: @LarsTech I updated the form code to show a more accurate picture of what is going on including dynamic generation of tab pages and dataGenerators. Hopefully this helps get to a resolution!

Comment: I would like to help, but your posted code is just riddled with errors.  `me.Controls.Add(newTab)`?  newTab is a TabPage.  StartGeneration throws an overflow exception.  You are missing the keyword `Sub` in those methods.  Attributes 1 & 2 are strings, you are passing numbers.  What are you doing with myDataGrids?  Other than that — your code works.

Comment: @LarsTech Sorry about the errors I guess I typed a little sloppily in my rush to post and get a solution to this. I added the sub keywords in. I removed the me.controls.add(newTab) (That wasn't actually in my code I accidently put it in the post as I rushed again). Then data generation  in the example isn't really important I just threw something together that I thought would generate lots of data. I changed it to use a thread to generate the data.

Comment: @LarsTech I forgot to answer your question about what I'm doing with the data. For the most part I just need to view it. There is also another button to export the data which is working fine. In my actual program the generated data is coming from a datastream from a PLC[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmable_logic_controller) and this is something to monitor them.

Comment: Now you are doing this all in a thread?  You should be getting cross-thread operation errors left and right.  Get rid of the thread.  You are still being *extremely* sloppy with your posted code.  You have myThread declared in the wrong class.  Your for...loop example still overflows (and is not declared correctly).  Still missing a bunch of `End Subs`.  Neatness counts in this profession.

Comment: Yes it's in a thread. I'm monitoring a number of live datastearms. There are some threadsafety precautions put into my code. (I looked at the wrong loop declaration last time or I would have fixed the i as i portion. Like I said before I just threw something together quick to generate data for an example. You can replace it with whatever works for you.

Comment: You're not getting threading errors?  You should be.  Your code is trying to update the UI with those events.

Comment: No my actual code runs fine There are datalocks and mutexs in it. I would post the actual code but there are confidentiality issues. The only problem is that that my datagrid's vertical scrollbar doesn't want to show up.